# Adding data to data grid from another thread (in another class)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem that has been driving me nuts for days.. I've tried so many tutorials and code snippets from this and many other websites. I am building a P2P application and i have problems accessing the main thread.
Here is the simple flow of my application:
1. frmMain is shown - user clicks on login button
2. frmlogin is shown - user enters his name
3. after "logging in" - two threads are created (threadTCPlistener and threadUDPlistener)
4. frmDataGrid is shown

```
Server listen = new Server();
Thread listeningUDPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listen.startUDPServer));
listeningUDPThread.IsBackground = true;
listeningUDPThread.Start();
Thread listeningTCPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listen.startTCPServer));
listeningTCPThread.IsBackground = true;
listeningTCPThread.Start();
frmDataGrid dg = new frmDataGrid();
dg.Show();
```

5.Threads work in one separate class called "Server". In there they wait for incoming connections, and when TCP thread accepts a connection it starts receinving a file. Upon receiving the file, I would like to change the GUI in the frmDataGrid to add a new row to grid view. I've done something like this:

```
public void downloadFile()
{
     //--receiving of the file--
     frmDataGrid fdg = new frmDataGrid();
     //filename is the name of received file, and 100's are just for testing (for now).    
     fdg.verifyUIRequest(fileName, 100, 100);
}
```

I am calling a method from frmDataGrid VerifyUIRequest that looks like this:

```
 public void verifyUIRequest(string filename, int done, int percent)
     {
     if (dgvDown.InvokeRequired)
         {
         dgvDown.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { updateDownDgv(filename, done, percent);  });
         }
     else
     {
         updateDownDgv(filename, done, percent);
     }
```

After this, the main thread should call the "updateDownDgv" method but the problem is that nothing is happening with my data grid. Here is the code for updating:

```
public void updateDownDgv(string filename, int done, int percent)
{
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvDown.Rows)
{
        if ((string)r.Cells[0].Value == filename)
                {
                    r.Cells[1].Value = done;
                    r.Cells[2].Value = percent;
                }
                dgvDown.Invalidate();
                return;
 }
 DataTable tab = (DataTable)dgvDown.DataSource;
 DataRow row =  tab.NewRow();
 row[0] = filename;
 row[1] = percent;
 row[2] = done;
 //MessageBox.Show(done.ToString());
 tab.Rows.Add(row);
 dgvDown.DataSource = null;
 dgvDown.DataSource = tab;
 }
```

I have tried doing this withh begin invoke, with some lambda expressions but nothing succeded. Can anyone please point me to an error or help in some other way? I would really appreciate it. 
PS This is my first post, so if it is poorly formatted, i apologize in advance. :)

EDIT:
So the problem is obviously with instances, so I've done something like this:
from Server class where I create an instance of my frmDataGrid class, i now call it's constructor that takes 3 arguments.
    frmDataGrid fdg = new frmDataGrid(fileName, 100, 100);
in that constructor, in frmDataGrid, I call verifyUIRequest. But then another error occurs, and I can't seem to figure it out. It stops at

```
if (dgvDown.InvokeRequired)
{...
```

error is as folows:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object", i.e. NullReferenceException. What could be the error?

Comment: I think it could help if you separate your problem. Try to update the grid without using threads at all and see if it is working. After that try to use threads but with no gui and see if that works. By combining them together from the beginning it is hard to solve.

Comment: Hi Amiram, the threads are working fine, they are able to show me mbox when they are done even the ones I put in `verifyUIRequest` method. Also, data grid can be updated directly (i.e. using main thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a brand new data grid in your `downloadFile` method. You should be updating the main grid and calling methods on that from your thread methods, not creating a new one that you drop on the floor when the `downloadFile` method exits.

Comment: in `downloadFile` I am just creating an instance of the class that has old data grid in her, not a new data grid. With that instance I am calling a method to update the old data grid called `dgvDown` (in `updateDgvDown`). I am not sure in what other way should I update my main data grid, besides this one I am using.

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you call "new" for this form twice then you have two data grids.

Comment: It might be, I am not sure, but either way, i should at least get the row added to this new grid, and be able to see it in my form. Or should I?

Comment: @epson121 - The only way you would see it in the form is if the new datagrid is on the form. If the new datagrid is not added to the form then you would not see any updates in the form. As to your first question, is `dgvDown` a global? You are not passing it to the `frmDataGrid` constructor.